# Embeding audio using textAngular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, audio

I want to embed an audio file using textAngular toolbar. This is the code which I used for the purpose.

```
userapp.config(function($provide){
$provide.decorator('taOptions', ['testFactory', 'taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(tFact, taRegisterTool, taOptions){
    console.log(taOptions);
    taRegisterTool('insertaudio', {
        iconclass: "fa fa-file-audio-o",
        buttontitle: 'Insert Image From Local Mechine or URL',
        action: function($deferred){
            this.$editor().wrapSelection('inserthtml','<audio controls="controls" SRC="http://olremix.org/mp3/Brunzolaitis_-_A_Link_To_OLR(Legend_of_Zelda_A_Link_to_the_Past).mp3"></audio>');
             $deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
    taOptions.toolbar[1].push('insertaudio');
    return taOptions;
}]);
```

});

But the problem is that it omits the audio tag whenever I try to save it. I tried the taApplyCustomRenderers. But even then it is not rendering it properly. It is inserting when i press the toolbar button. But when I try to save the file it just omits the audio tag and all its attributes. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added audio tag to angular-sanitize.js and it solved my problem.